# Crash iPhone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging, crash

I have developed an application on iPhone.

If i run it from XCode, no problem : XCode installs the app on the device, then the app is running, OK.

But then, I unplug the device from Mac, and i run the app : crash happens, OK.

I would like to know if there is a way to attach XCode as debugger when I run an app from the device, and not from XCode. Such like Windbg and dump of application crashed.

Answer (score 1):

If you re-attach your device to XCode, you can access the crash log.

Go to the Organizer, select Devices, select your device, and then under your device name, you will see "Device Logs".  You will be able to select and examine any of them in the next window to the right.

You will also be able to see the Console.

These should help in determining what caused the crash.

[image: organizer screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is mostly due to memory issue. Check in instruments that your application consumes more memory. If so try to reduce memory conception by releasing unnecessary view controllers and mostly UIImageViews